# Title of this puzzle? You tell me

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

**What's the answer to this puzzle?**

---

[image]

```
                            98989576412452356298989576412452654...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The puzzle is named

> [Für Elise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%BCr_Elise)

because

> the picture represents a piano keyboard with | for white notes and ' for black notes.

Thus the numbers

> 123456789 represent the notes C E G# A B C D D# E and the sequence of numbers 989895... plays out the tune.

ETA: as noted in the comments by the setter

> The coloured dots were intended to encode the composer's name. There are fifty-two white keys; twenty-six on the left and thenty-six on the right. The red dots pick out the 4th, 7th, 9th, 12th, 21st and 23rd of the left keys which correspond to the letters D, G, I, L, U, W (which are the letters of LUDWIG) and the blue dots pick out the 1st, 2nd, 5th, 8th, 14th, 15th, 20th and 22nd of the right keys which correspond to the letters A, B, E, H, N, O, T, V (which are the letters of VAN BEETHOVEN).

Comment: and the red and blue dots?

Comment: Shouldn't it be 989895…?

Comment: @Someone Just so, now corrected.

Comment: Well done! That's the title. rot13(gur qbgf jurer whfg na rkgen srngher, gurl pbeerfcbaq gb gur svefg naq ynfg anzr. Gur juvgr xrlf, orvat 52, unq n qbhoyr zrnavat va pnfr fbzrbar fgnegrq pbhagvat naq pbhyqa'g znxr frafr bs gur zrnavat bs gur chmmyr. Gurl pna or fcyvg va gjb cnegf. Rnpu jvgu N-M. Erq pbeerfcbaqf gb gur yrggref bs Yhqjvt, oyhr pbeerfcbaqf gb gur yrggref bs Ina Orrgubira. V frr abj gung V sbetbg n yrggre, jvyy rqvg).